# Tab bar item tag issue in swift

Tags: ios, tabs

I have a view controller in which there is tab bar inside the tab bar i have four tab bar items. I have set tag for each of the items. I want to open view controller when user click on any tab bar item. I have used a delegate method of tab bar to make this happen. Now when i click any item it open only first view controller on each tab bar item. My code is this,

```
 func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    if stateBtn.tag == 1 {
        let vcName = "StatesViewController"

        let viewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcName)
        self.revealViewController().pushFrontViewController(viewController, animated: true)

    } else if bidBtn.tag == 2 {

        let vcName = "FindBidsViewController"

        let viewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcName)
        self.revealViewController().pushFrontViewController(viewController, animated: true)

    }else if categoryBtn.tag == 3{

        let vcName = "CategoriesViewController"

        let viewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcName)
        self.revealViewController().pushFrontViewController(viewController, animated: true)

    }else{

        let vcName = "RFPSearchViewController"

        let viewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcName)
        self.revealViewController().pushFrontViewController(viewController, animated: true)

    }
}
```

I have set its delegate to self also.But it is opening only one view controller for all items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking

```
if stateBtn.tag == 1
```

which is always true so first condition will always execute. Instead you should use

```
if item.tag == 1
```

because item is the reference to the tab bar item clicked.

Comment: so what to set for the first time? @sumesh shivan

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code to detect which item is clicked.

switch item.tag {
     case 0:
        print("First Item")
     case 1:
        print("Second Item")
     case 2:
        print("Third Item")
     case 3:
        print("Fourth Item")
     default: break
}

Hope this would help you.
```